# Theme for beamer?

Tags: beamer

I was excited when saw [Designing Math Fonts](http://www.typoma.com/publ/20040430-bachotex.pdf) presentation and other similar presentations mentioned at [How do I know if a math font fits well with the text font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26741/how-do-i-know-if-a-math-font-fits-well-with-the-text-font). These presentations are presumably prepared with the use of `beamer` class. Does anybody know how these presentations were done. Is there publically available theme for the `beamer` class which gives this look to presentaions?

Comment: One of them seems to be `Singapore` theme and other based on `Dresden` with some customization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [beamer theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix) which shows an example of each beamer theme (rows) with every color theme (columns).

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look into the already existing themes which are saved in  the directory of the beamer class file: `.../beamer/themes/theme`

```
beamerthemeAnnArbor.sty  beamerthemeboxes.sty        beamerthemeFrankfurt.sty    beamerthemeMadrid.sty       beamerthemeRochester.sty
beamerthemeAntibes.sty   beamerthemeCambridgeUS.sty  beamerthemeGoettingen.sty   beamerthemeMalmoe.sty       beamerthemeSingapore.sty
beamerthemeBergen.sty    beamerthemeCopenhagen.sty   beamerthemeHannover.sty     beamerthemeMarburg.sty      beamerthemeSzeged.sty
beamerthemeBerkeley.sty  beamerthemeDarmstadt.sty    beamerthemeIlmenau.sty      beamerthemeMontpellier.sty  beamerthemeWarsaw.sty
beamerthemeBerlin.sty    beamerthemedefault.sty      beamerthemeJuanLesPins.sty  beamerthemePaloAlto.sty     compatibility
beamerthemeBoadilla.sty  beamerthemeDresden.sty      beamerthemeLuebeck.sty      beamerthemePittsburgh.sty
```